# How to push data over URL with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to figure out how to use the URL below to send SMS messages dynamicaly to users who sign up via a form.

In the form I have:

```
<input type="tel" name="usrtel">
```

On form submit I want the value of `<input name="usrtel">` (e.i. the users mobilnumber) to be inserted into `targetNumbers=`, in the url below, and then execute that url.

```
https://admin.intouch.no/smsgateway/sendSms?sender=CompanyName&targetNumbers=12345678&sms=Testmessage&userName=foo&password=bar
```

Documentation on how to use the SMS service can be found at http://bit.ly/TmQ30D

Can anyone please help me figure out how to figure this out?

This is what I got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/iamchriswick/A8Etr/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see your fiddle by the time I posted. Here's mine:
http://jsfiddle.net/lsubirana/6tvXQ/

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'https://admin.intouch.no/smsgateway/sendSms',
        data:{
            'sender':'CompanyName',
            'targetNumbers':$('input[name=usrtel]').val(),
            'sms':'Testmessage',
            'userName':'foo',
            'password':'bar'
            },
      type:'GET',
      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings){
        console.log(settings.url);
        alert(settings.url);
      },
      success: function(res) {

       }

   });
```

I would use the jQuery ajax method's "data" object to keep your form's data separate from the url in your code... things are a little cleaner that way.

Comment: Follow up question: The code functions fine in the jsFiddle, but when I try to use it on my server i get a similar error to this.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://admin.intouch.no/smsgateway/sendSms?sender=CompanyName&targetNumbers=&sms=Testmessage&userName=foo&password=bar. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://domian.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Any idea how to get around that?

Comment: Your page with the script is not on the same server as admin.intouch.no? This SO question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Comment: Thanks again :) I found the answer in this post: http://bit.ly/1hEggms I just added `crossDomain: true` and `dataType: 'jsonp'`, and so far it seems to be working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go..!!

```
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://admin.intouch.no/smsgateway/sendSms?sender=CompanyName&targetNumbers=12345678&sms=Testmessage&userName=foo&password=bar',
      type:'GET',
      success: function(res) {
          //do stuff 
       }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks! But how exactly would I implement this? Take a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iamchriswick/A8Etr/1/

Comment: if (formSubmit.valid()) 
{
    //send the ajax request
    $.ajax({ ... }) 
}